# Powershell: Passing Credentials in a PSSession to a machine returns Incorrect network password

Tags: windows, powershell

Just some notes:

- The issue that is being faced does not happen on every machine, only 1 in 20
- I know it is not a powershell issue, but need to know from a health perspective what could cause this
- The machine allows a connection with an Admin account over the PS Port, but after that the machine does not see the rights of the account
- If I pass the Credentials using a Get-Credential rather than a PS Credential Object, it works however this is not an acceptable solution as the script it being wrapped in an MSO Runbook

Code being used for Credentials:

```
$Username = "domainname\userid"  
$Password = "P@s4w0rd1!" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force  
$mycreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $Password
```

Code for the PSSession:

```
$Session1 = New-PSSession -ComputerName WorkstationNAme #Connects to the computer
Invoke-Command -Session $Session1 -ScriptBlock {
$FreeDrive = (68..90 | %{$L=[char]$_; if ((gdr).Name -notContains $L) {$L}})[0] #Grabs the first available Drive Letter
$execDriveLocation = New-PSDrive -Name $FreeDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Using:Variable1 -Credential $using:mycreds -Persist #Creates temporary mapped drive
}
```

Error Returned on the affected machines:

```
The specified network password is not correct
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (D:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
    + PSComputerName        : computername
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Please, try to create a [mcve] as I suspect that you leaving out the concerned details required to resolve this. According to error message, the issue is in the `New-PSDrive` command which doesn't show from your code. Long shot: [Mapped drives are not available from an elevated prompt when UAC is configured to Prompt for credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drives-not-available-from-elevated-command)

Comment: At the very least include the `New-PSDrive` invocation